# insert query in sql from another table with running number

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Am inserting rows in the table from another table

I need to the id columns should be running number like the below how to do that

i have set id column is unique key, so that the below code shows error

```
insert into Tbl1 (Id, DislayName,IsEnabled)
select 16000,Names,0 from Tbl2
```

Insertion should be like

```
16000 | John  | false
16001 | Deo   | false
16002 | Jake  | false
```

NOTE: no auto increment should be used, because already its been assigned for another column

Comment: Set the Indentity specification  (Is Identity) to Yes Identity Increment to 1 and Identity Seed to 16000 by selecting the ID column in design view of source table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `row_number()` window function (minus one)

```
insert into Tbl1 (Id, DislayName,IsEnabled)
select 16000 -1 + row_number () over (order by Names),
       Names,0 
  from Tbl2;
```

Comment: you need to add concat names as well

Comment: @TheGameiswar I think Name1, Name2 are just values of column `Names`  on `tbl2`